# I have one N-queen problem As I want to know the approach I am using is correct or not

Tags: python

My concern is that I have problem of N*N chess board in which I have to place my queen in such a way that no other queen should be attack over each other either in row, column or diagonal, So my first approach is I have taken a variable in which I have value of 0 and I am letting that **(1)** will be the position of queen , so `

```
          board = [[0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

What should be the first approach of the same. please help
`

I want to print the place of queen where no queen should be attack each other in N*N chess board

Comment: You could fill all the positions that your queen can see with "2"s; then the available positions for another queen are those with val "0".

Answer (score 0):

There's a much better approach than your first:

If you take into consideration that each queen will have to occupy one column and one row, You realize that the queen positions form a bijection from {A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H} to {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}. Once you've figured how to enumerate only these bijections, you only have to filter the ones which have two queens in a diagonal and you're good.

Comment: As It Seems quite difficult to understand . Please let me know At first will I have to take a variable and store value??